# How to count non-zero values in a dataframe inside a range of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe, and I want to count the non-zero values of a column, the only problem is that I want to count those values in a moving window. For example, I have this:

```
df.loc[i:j,'data']
```

Now I want to count all the non-zero values on the column 'data' within this [i:j] range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
sum(df.loc[i:j,'data'].ne(0))
#or
df.loc[i:j,'data'].ne(0).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I was stuck with that simple code line.